# Schema.rb blank after transition to PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

So after having a problem deploying to Heroku for the first time, I wanted to get my dev environment running Postgres..

That's when i couldn't get my dev environment working. My errors lie in the database. I'm running Rails 3.2, Postgres.app, I got a database setup, I think `database.yml` is good to go.

As far as I can tell, my `schema.rb` is blank. It originally was not. When i delete it and reset the database, the new `schema.rb` is still blank. Where does schema get it's information from?

`Rake db:migrate` returns this `SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations"`

The `rails s` error complains about the lack of a users table.. doh.

I admittedly edited the schema.rb early on when i was first starting. But I don't know what caused this sort of reset.

`database.yml`

```
development:
 adapter: postgresql
 database: phriends
 encoding: utf8
 username: mrbubbles
 password:

test:
 adapter: postgresql
 database: test
 encoding: utf8
 username: mrbubbles
 password:

production:
 adapter: postgresql
 database: production_database
 encoding: utf8
 username: mrbubbles
 password:
```

Comment: How did you set up your local PostgreSQL database?

Comment: I `psql` and `CREATE DATABASE`, then pointed `database.yml`. I temporarily fixed this problem by copying in my old schema.rb... guess that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you didn't `rake db:setup`, `db:setup` will

> Create the database, load the schema, and initialize with the seed data (use `db:reset` to also drop the db first)

Note the "load the schema" part, that would read `schema.rb` and build the tables based on what it says. So restore your `schema.rb` and do a `db:setup`.